# Getting the ID of a user by the name, tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

How can i get the id of a user with the tweepy library if i have the user screen name. I don't seem to find a way to store any of the users data without having previously the users ID

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the user id with:

```
user = api.get_user(screen_name) 
user._json['id']
```